# Python - Send value to page and scrape output

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I deleted my original post and am posting a cleaner version since I learned a bit more.

This page
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=azure-sentinel
has a calculator when you scroll down.

**GOAL:
I want to be able to submit values to the text boxes for "Logs Ingested" and "Logs Retention (Months)", and scrape the value from "Monthly Cost"**

I played with Selenium just to be able to form the logic, I got somewhat far into it but ultimately abandoned because I don't want a browser to pop up.

I heard Mechanize can submit forms, but I'm not sure if this page uses forms. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=azure-sentinel')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

//textbox for log volume
logvolume = soup.find(xpath='/html/body/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/input')
print (logvolume)

//textbox for log retention
logretention = soup.find(xpath='/html/body/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/input')
print (logretention)

//output for monthly cost
price = soup.find(xpath='/html/body/main/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div[2]/span[2]/span')
print (price)
```